# nginx sending extra data after php echo message

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I have a software written in c++ using curl to get information from my webserver. I wrote the web code in php. What basically happens is after the information is gathered I display it on the php page using echo, and at any call, there is only a single echo being called.

Now when running nginx on the server there are extra lines at the end of the message:

---

[2017/12/3 15:15:13] response: expected size: 27: rZXkxMjsyNTMjMxOTkyMTQ3ODs=

(empty line)

0

(empty line)

(empty line)

(empty line)

(empty line)

---

And this is the reply when running apache2:

---

[2017/12/3 15:15:43] response: expected size: 27: rZXkxMjsyNTMjMxOTkyMTQ3ODs=

---

This gets even worse when the message is longer, as it gets devided to chunks, and there are garbage being displayed between the chunks on nginx, making the reply incorrect. Works fine on apache2 even when only chunks are being sent.

My questions is, what could cause this issue on nginx? Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out turning off chunked transfer encoding in the nignx.conf fixes the problem:

chunked_transfer_encoding off;